# I ended up with two accounts. How can I combine them?

Tags: support

I somehow ended up with two accounts:

- https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/users/44636/user44636
- https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/users/44637/user143758

How can I combine them? I'm now locked out from accessing user44636, but I used the same email when I created it.